# Why do I get same p.adjusted both for Benjamini Hochberg and Bonferroni correlation test

Tags: r, statistics, statistics-bootstrap, bonferroni

Hello statisticians and R experts,
Why do I get the same results for BH and Bonferroni tests?

my code:

```
dpnd<-c(rnorm(25,mean = 0),rnorm(25,mean=1))
indpnd<-c(rep("a",25),rep("b",25))


bonf <- pairwise.t.test(dpnd, indpnd, p.adjust.method="bonferroni")
bonf

BH <- pairwise.t.test(dpnd, indpnd, p.adjust.method="BH")
BH
```

Results:

```
> bonf <- pairwise.t.test(dpnd, indpnd, p.adjust.method="bonferroni")
> bonf

    Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  dpnd and indpnd 

  a      
b 2.3e-05

P value adjustment method: bonferroni 
> 
> BH <- pairwise.t.test(dpnd, indpnd, p.adjust.method="BH")
> BH

    Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  dpnd and indpnd 

  a      
b 2.3e-05

P value adjustment method: BH
```

Do I not understand something?
I would like some help over here!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example includes a single pair, no adjustment has been applied. Try again with `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: I should not have any more data to use. Only a & b. would you recommend a different way to preform those tests?